# Error modal sample with super outside constructor

Tags: react-native

Anyone can help me fix this error when using code modal sample in link https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html I can't understand why this error appear although i coded absolutely same code sample.
[image: error]

Comment: Please post code as **plain text** in the body of your question. Adding it as an image makes it very difficult for people to adapt your code to an answer, you can't copy-paste it, and it's hostile to those dependent on screen-readers

Answer (score 1):

Use `ES6` class. Constructor will work only on `ES6` class.

```
class ModalExample extends React.Component {
   constructor () {
       super(props)
   }
   render () {
     // code
   }
}
```

If you don't want to use ES6 class, then use `getInitialState` to set the state.

```
var ModalExample = React.createClass ({
     getInitialState: function() {
          return {
               modalVisible: false
          }
     }
})
```